# Can't change endTime in CountDownTimer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I want to create a countdown timer in my flutter app and I used ***flutter_countdown_timer*** to make it. In my app I used the below code;

```
CountdownTimer(
                  endTime: 1594829147719,
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.white),
                  defaultDays: "==",
                  defaultHours: "--",
                  defaultMin: "**",
                  defaultSec: "++",
                  daysSymbol: "Days ",
                  hoursSymbol: "Hrs ",
                  minSymbol: "Mins ",
                  secSymbol: "Secs",
                ),
```

In the above if I change the ***endTime*** from ***1594829147719*** to some other value this timer stops working and doesn't give any output.

What can be the possible cause for this and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a timer from scratch.

```
int timerSeconds;
DateTime startedAt;


StartTimer(){

_timer= new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => {

      setState(() {
        startedAt=DateTime.now();
        seconds--;
      })
    });
}
//to format the timer text
 String _printDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }

String getTimerText(){
   int timePassed= DateTime.now().difference(startedAt).inSeconds;
   timerTextString=_printDuration(Duration(seconds: timerText-timePassed));
}
```

Then stop the timer when disposing of.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Then call the text string in Text widget like this

```
Text(getTimerText());
```